# PHP: Is it possible to set the domain when creating a session?

Tags: php

On mydomain.com if I run this code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['close_label'] = '1';
```

and then onspect the session cookie in my browser, it says:

> domain: .mydomain.com

Is it possible to have it say:

> domain: .someotherdomain.com

or not?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: like sso you can take something like p3p http://www.w3.org/P3P/ a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set cookies for a completely different domain. That would be a security nightmare. You can set cookies for the current domain and/or subdomains of it. That's all.